# Manually install Gradle and use it in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio. How can I manually install and use `Gradle` within `Android Studio`.

I've downloaded `Gradle` from http://www.gradle.org/downloads version gradle-2.1-all.zip.

When I open the zipped file I can see bin, docs etc, but I don't know where to copy it. And even after copying how to use it within Android..

Comment: File > Settings > Gradle > Use local gradle distribution

Comment: Nobody said what path exacty should be used in local distribution.

Comment: @SwapnilPopat I added an answer with all the details needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54924485

Comment: what about if we edit the gradle-wrapper.properties manually without going to the settings and other stuffs?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Android Studio will automatically use the Gradle wrapper and pull the correct version of Gradle rather than use a locally installed version.  If you wish to use a new version of Gradle, you can change the version used by studio.  Beneath your Android Studio's project tree, open the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.  Change this entry:

`distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip`

Comment: I am  using my laptop offline, so I want to download and use from another source. Which is why am trying to do this manually.

Comment: Try temporarily changing the `distributionUrl` line to point to the zip on your filesystem, run your build (e.g. `gradlew assemble`) then when it is done change it to the correct URL.  That should force Gradle to "download" the package from your filesystem and set it up as it expects, while leaving other machines ok when you commit the `gradle` directory to your VCS.

Comment: after two days, i see clear with you reply, a lot of methods on the web with grep, etc, and it was simple

Comment: @TanyavonDegurechaff Check this answer which contains more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54924485

Answer (score 71):

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Download The Latest Gradle Distribution File and Extract It, Then Copy all Files and Paste it Under:

`C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.gradle\wrapper\dists\`

Comment: With android-studio 3.3, this won't work, unless you know exact hash, and put it under the hash dir.

Comment: @EricWang First you can let android studio start the download, then you stop it, and locate the file as Hackbal said, you will find the hash already created

Comment: and how do you start android studio to download?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano Then Just Start Android Studio as Normal. After Build Complete it will be work

Answer (score 29):

Step 1: Go to the download site from Gradle: https://gradle.org/releases/

Step 2: Extract the downloaded zip file into a directory.

Step 2: Hit Ctrl + Alt + S (mac: ⌘ + ,) in Android studio/Intellij IDEA

Step 3: Goto: Build, Execution, Deployment >> Build Tools >> Gradle (Or just type in the searchbar Gradle)

Step 4: Select: (X) Use local gradle distribution and set Gradle home to your extracted Gradle directory. Click on apply.

Step 5: Get rid of your unnecessary gradle files delete: 
**- MyApp/gradle/** 

**- gradlew** 

**- gradlew.bat**

Comment: Thank you Lee i edited my mistake. It is indeed Ctrl+ Alt + S instead of Ctrl+ Shift + S.

Comment: Where do you press CTRL-ALT-S? in windows explorer after extracting the files?

Comment: @AaA In Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA, this shortcut opens your IDEA settings menu. I updated your feedback thank you.

Comment: This works, but each time open project, android-studio will ask to confirm whether use gradlew instead. And I can't find an option to ignore that.

Answer (score 17):

*(There are 2 solutions mentioned in existing answers that might work, but the preferred one - manually download gradle for `gradlew`, is lack of essential details, and cause it fail. So, I would add a summary with missing details to save the unnecessary time wasted, in case others encounter into the same issue.)*

There are 2 possible solutions:

---

**Solution A:** Use location `gradle`, and delete `gradlew` related files. ***(not recommend)***

Refer to this answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29198101/

**Tips:**

- I tried, it works, though this is not suggested for gradle use in general.
- And, with this solution, each time open project, android-studio will ask to confirm whether to use gradlew instead, it's kinda annoying.

---

**Solution B:** Download `gradle` distribution manually for `gradlew`. ***(recommended)***

Android Studio will download gradle to sub dir named by a hash.
To download manually, need to download to the exact sub dir named by the hash.

**Steps:**

- **Get the hash.**

  - Start android-studio.
  - Create a basic project.
  - Then it will create the hash, and start to download gradle.
    e.g `.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/`
  - Close android-studio.
  - Find the download process, by android-studio.
    e.g `ps -aux grep | android`
  - Kill all the related android processes.
  - Remove the blank project.
- **Download gradle by hand.**

  - Go to the hash folder.
    e.g `.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/`
  - There is a partly download file.
    e.g `gradle-4.10.1-all.zip.part`
  - Download the exact version by hand.
    from website:   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
    e.g https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
  - Remove the `*.part` file.
  - And copy the download file there instead.
    e.g `.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`
- **Start `Android Studio` and try again.**

  - Create a new blank project again.
  - Then it shouldn't need to download gradle again.
  - It will uncompress gradle in the the same dir.
    e.g `.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/gradle-4.10.1/`
  - And starts to sync dependencies, indexing, and build.

**Tips:**

- After restart `Android Studio` & creating blank project again, if you see it says waiting for other process to download the distribution.
  That means you didn't kill the previous download process, kill it first, then remove blank project, then create a new project to confirm again.
- Each version of `Android Studio` might use different `gradle` version, thus might need to repeat this process once, when `Android Studio` is upgraded.

**BTW**:

- Here is the dir layout on my `Linux`
  *(For `Android Studio 3.3.1`, which use `gradle` 4.10.1)*

  eric@eric-pc:`~/.gradle/wrapper`$ **`tree -L 4`**

  ```
  .
  └── dists
      └── gradle-4.10.1-all
          └── 455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd
              ├── gradle-4.10.1
              ├── gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
              ├── gradle-4.10.1-all.zip.lck
              └── gradle-4.10.1-all.zip.ok
  ```

---

**Suggestions to `Android-Studio`**

- Since it's so slow when download gradle distrbution within `Android Studio`.
  It's better to provide an option to choose local `gradle` installation dir or .zip file to be used by `gradlew`.

Comment: but how to set up `gradle.properties` then? For example, I want to add `parallel` property but I do not want to change `gradle.properties` from the team project.

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko Does following answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333837/where-to-put-the-gradle-properties-file

Comment: The option to use local gradle was there in earlier versions of android studio (version 3x) , then some bone head admin within the android team removed it in Android studio 4x.

Answer (score 11):

1.Download the Gradle form [gradle distribution](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

2.Extract file to some location

3.Open **Android Studio** : **File > Settings > Gradle > Use local gradle
distribution** navigate the path where you have extracted the gradle.

4.click apply and ok

Done

EDIT 1: In the latest version of AS, the option is called "Use Gradle from: Specified location, thanks @Adam Burley for suggestion

Comment: Which version of Android studio your answer applies to? in Android Studio 2.3.3 there is no Gradle under Settings Window (it is under Build, ... ) and it does not have such option as Use Local gradle distribuition

Comment: file->setting->Build,Execute,Deployment-> Gradle. then select Use Local gradle distribution check box and give the gradle path

Comment: i think he is using android studio 3 and not version 2.

Comment: In the latest version of AS, the option is called "Use Gradle from: Specified location"

Answer (score 9):

Assuming this is a windows system and we are using **gradle-2.1-all**  [Applicable to any gradle version, just change the version as we need]

> All the gradles can be found in
>   http://services.gradle.org/distributions/

---

Check the `<Your Project>\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`
Make sure the **distributionUrl** is

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
```

This is enough as it will automatically download the gradle.

> After doing the above stuff,
>   if you have downloaded the zip, paste the **gradle-2.1-all.zip** in
>
> ```
> C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.1-all\<some_hash_key>\
> ```
>
> It will save the extra downloading time.

Comment: Read the question again! it is asking `Manually`! and yet your answer says `automatically` in an OFFLINE machine there is no way to download automatically!

Comment: how to get the hash key

Answer (score 7):

I used like this,

```
distributionUrl=file\:///E\:/Android/Gradle/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

And its worked for me.

Comment: where do you add this?

Comment: In gradle-wrapper.properties.

Answer (score 4):

download the desired pacakge
Then modify the distribution line to

```
distributionUrl=file:/c:/Gradle/gradle-5.5.1-all.zip
```

Comment: i think you have to escape the ':' with \:

Comment: @Eboubaker thanks your notice was very usefull :)

Answer (score 3):

Unpack it where ever you like. In Android Studio under Settings is category Gradle where you can specify external gradle location if you want.
It probably makes sense to put gradle bin folder into your path.

Comment: Should I define Environment variables for Gradle to get it to work? If so how?

Comment: No, you dont need any special environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Download the latest Gradle distribution

Step 2. Unpack the distribution

Microsoft Windows users

Create a new directory C:\Gradle with File Explorer.

Open a second File Explorer window and go to the directory where the Gradle distribution was downloaded. Double-click the ZIP archive to expose the content. Drag the content folder gradle-4.1 to your newly created C:\Gradle folder.

Alternatively you can unpack the Gradle distribution ZIP into C:\Gradle using an archiver tool of your choice.

Step 3. Configure your system environment

Microsoft Windows users

In File Explorer right-click on the This PC (or Computer) icon, then click Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables.

Under System Variables select Path, then click Edit. Add an entry for C:\Gradle\gradle-4.1\bin. Click OK to save.

Step 4. Verify your installation

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why there are so many contorted descriptions of doing
 this. Perhaps because Android Studio (AS) is constantly
 changing/evolving? Nevertheless, the procedure is *this* simple.

Assuming you have already installed Gradle in a suitable directory, mean that you probably also defined an environment variable for `GRADLE_HOME`, if not define it now, and restart AS.

For my example: `GRADLE_HOME=C:\Gradle\gradle-5.2.1`

Then fire up AS and navigate to:
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle

Now, all you need to do is to select: `(o) Use local gradle distribution`. 
AS will then tell you it found your local Gradle paths:

[image]

Hit `Apply` and `Ok` and restart AS.

Now all the Gradle data can be found in your *HOME* directory, usually located here (in this case on Windows):

```sh
# tree -L 2 $USERPROFILE/.gradle/ | tail -n +2

├── build-scan-data
│   ├── 2.1
│   └── 2.2.1
├── caches
│   ├── 3.5
│   ├── 5.2.1
│   ├── jars-3
│   ├── journal-1
│   ├── modules-2
│   ├── transforms-1
│   ├── transforms-2
│   ├── user-id.txt
│   └── user-id.txt.lock
├── daemon
│   ├── 3.5
│   └── 5.2.1
├── native
│   ├── 25
│   ├── 28
│   └── jansi
├── notifications
│   └── 5.2.1
├── workers
└── wrapper
    └── dists
```

<sub>Tested on latest AS 3.3.2</sub>

Comment: In the latest version of AS, the option is called "Use Gradle from: Specified location"

Comment: @AdamBurley Even though I have set "Specific Location" to my system gradle, The build logs shows it still uses inbuild gradle. Funny thing is that when I went to write gradle path, it automatically detected its location based on my system env variables.

On side note, I can't find option to use system kotlin compiler in last few versions. Inbuilt compiler is slow, I remember in old version, I could use system kotlin which improved build time performance by a lot.

Answer (score 2):

in first step you should go to http://www.gradle.org/downloads and then choose your Gradle version and follow download link in GitHub and then download Gradle from GitHub.
after your download is completed, you should extract the downloaded file in a directory (every directory that you want).
finally open extracted folder and just run gradlew.bat and wait several minutes for completing download. and after completing download files, Gradle install itself automaticly.
Gradle will work correctly for next times.
i resolve this problem with this way and i tested it and every things are ok, so every one can test this way, it should working well.
Good Luck.

Comment: Read the question again! it is asking `Manually`! and yet your answer says `automatically` in an `OFFLINE machine` there is no way to download automatically!

Answer (score 2):

Like @ said

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Download The Latest Gradle Distribution File and Extract It, Then Copy all Files and Paste it Under:

`C:\Users\{USERNAME}\.gradle\wrapper\dists\`

but you have to first make **Android Studio** try downloading the zip file and cancel it.

That way you can get the *hash* and copy the file and put it under the hash

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

1. Download gradle
2. Extract the file to a specific location you desire
3. Open android studio
   Click on setting and on build, execution and deployment, then gradle
4. Enable work offline and change service directory to the location of the extracted filed.

This is what worked for me. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the gralde to your computer
2. Extract the file to any folder of your choice

Now there are two ways you can tell Android studio to use the downloaded gradle

1. Go to "AndroidStudio->Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->BuildTools->Gradle" and update "Use Gradle from:" to Specified location and set your path

[image]

2. Go to gradle-wrapper.properties file in your project. This will be located in "YourAppFolder->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties"
   Edit the distributionUrl for example

> distributionUrl=file:/Users/john/downloads/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

### If you are on **LINUX** follow the steps below:

- Go to the download https://gradle.org/ and download the latest zip file (currently 3.1 is the latest version)
- Extract the downloaded zip file into /opt/android-studio/gradle/.
- Open your project in Android Studio and hit Ctrl + Alt + S
- Search for Gradle in the Search bar of the setting window
- Select: (X) Use local gradle distribution and set Gradle home to /opt/andriod-studio/gradle/gradle.x.x (where x.x is the vesrion of the gradle zip file you just downloaded.). Then click on apply.
- Try to sync Gradle again if the sync has already failed.If not close your project and reopen your project.

  Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, you have installed the latest gradle once. But, If your particular project gradle version not match with the gradle version that already installed in the machine, the gradle sycn want to download that version. To prevent this download there is one trick. First You have to know the gradle version that already installed in your machine. Go to : C:\Users{username}.gradle\wrapper\dists, here you see the versions allready installed, remember the latest version, assume it is gradle-6.1.1-all.zip . Now, come back to Android Studio. In your Opened project, navigate Android Studio's project tree, open the file gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. Change this entry:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

This way we prevent downloading the gradle again and again. But avoid this thing, if the version really old. If that, you will find this warning :

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Debian Distrubition
I simply set

`distributionUrl=file:///home/freduah/.GradleZip/gradle-6.7-all.zip`

Android Studio  Version ---- 4.2.1

OS ----- Kali GNU/Linux Rolling

Follow The Following Steps Remember It's Android Studio Version 4.2.1

`In the Project Directory Go To android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

You Could set it with this syntax

`distributionUrl=file:///home/<username>/pathToFile/nameOfFile.extensionType`

Answer (score -3):

1.Install gardle as per the given link http://services.gradle.org/distributions/
2.Extract this downloaded file in C:\Gradle\gradle-4.5
location
3.set the environment of gradle
This PC\properties\advance system settings\Environment variable
4.let's start Android studio
And set the path of gradle 
C:\Gradle\gradle
In Android studio