# Where to put the gradle.properties file

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, artifactory

I am following the Artifactory [1-min Setup](http://www.jfrog.com/video/artifactory-1-min-setup/). I have Artifactory up and running on my localhost, and now I am trying to integrate it with Intellij/Gradle.

The artifactory webapp gives a `gradle.properties` and `build.gradle` file, so I'm trying to start with adding these to my IntelliJ project. However, I don't know where to put the `gradle.properties` file.

I tried copying the`gradle.properties` contents (key=value pairs) to `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, unfortunately doing that does not make the keys accessible in the `build.gradle` file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Gradle looks for `gradle.properties` files in these places:

- in project build dir (that is where your build script is)
- in sub-project dir
- in gradle user home (defined by the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable, which if not set defaults to `USER_HOME/.gradle`)

Properties from one file will override the properties from the previous ones (so file in gradle user home has precedence over the others, and file in sub-project has precedence over the one in project root).

Reference: https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I added the gradle.properties file to the project dir and now it the keys are resolved in the build.gradle file.

Comment: But we can we use both properties of both `gradle.properties` file that is under `GRADLE_USER_HOME` as well as the one that is  in root project directory right?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS No, not the file, but the key/value will be overrided.

Comment: I'm not a fan of blind references like these. Though convention over configuration has its advantages.

Answer (score 64):

Actually there are 3 places where `gradle.properties` can be placed:

1. Under gradle user home directory defined by the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable, which if not set defaults to USER_HOME/.gradle
2. The sub-project directory (`myProject2` in your case)
3. The root project directory (under `myProject`)

Gradle looks for `gradle.properties` in all these places while giving precedence to properties definition based on the order above. So for example, for a property defined in gradle user home directory (#1) and the sub-project (#2) its value will be taken from gradle user home directory (#1).

You can find more details about it in gradle documentation **[here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)**.