# In Gradle, how to print out a message in the console / Event Log?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, logging, build.gradle

I'm trying to verify that my source and target paths are properly setup when I execute a deploy command.

See the example below:
(copied from: http://eppz.eu/blog/unity-android-plugin-tutorial-2/)

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    // Task names.
    String variantName = "${variant.name.capitalize()}"; // Like 'Debug'
    String deployTaskGroup = "plugin";
    String deployTaskName = "deploy${variantName}PluginArchive"; // Like 'deployDebugPluginArchive'
    String dependencyTaskName = "assemble${variantName}"; // Like 'assembleDebug'
    // Source.
    String sourceAARFolder = "${buildDir.getPath()}/outputs/aar/";
    String sourceAARName = "${project.name}-${variant.name}.aar";
    // Target.
    String targetAssetFolder = "Assets/Plugins/My Plugin";
    String targetAARFolder = "${rootDir.getPath()}/../../${targetAssetFolder}"; // Navigate into 'Assets'
    String targetAARName = "My Plugin Android.aar"; // The form you ship your plugin

    String targetProjDir = System.env.UNITY_PROJECT; // <-- Need to confirm this line!
    //Log.i(targetProjDir); //??????????? something like this?

    // Create task.
    task(deployTaskName, dependsOn: dependencyTaskName, type: Copy) {
        from(sourceAARFolder)
        into(targetAARFolder)
        include(sourceAARName)
        rename(sourceAARName, targetAARName)
    }.group = deployTaskGroup;
}
```

Is there any way to display the above `targetProjDir` string variable to some sort of console, or the Event Log in Android Studio (assuming that is it's console's name)?

Comment: I think I just figured it out, didn't notice the `Gradle Console` until now. A simple `printf "Your String here..."` seems to do the trick.

Comment: ^ that being said, it seems to print it out twice in a row everytime I run any 'assemble...', 'build...' or 'deploy...' Gradle commands. What could be causing the duplicate prints?

Comment: `System.out.println(message);`

Comment: I gotta say, I'm surprised this question still gets quite a few visits / votes to this day! Would of imagined there would be better alternatives / simplified build-workflows for Android by now. Glad this question sheds some lights to others! Good luck!

Comment: @chamberlainpi Why didn't you accept an answer?

Answer (score 165):

Gradle utilizes a logging framework. You can log messages to that.  By default, only log level `lifecycle` and above are shown, but you can log at other levels such as `debug` and `info`.

To log at debug level (visible with builds using `gradle --debug` or lower)

```
project.logger.debug('my debug message')
```

To log at info level (visible with `gradle --info` builds and lower)

```
project.logger.info('my info message')
```

To log at lifecycle level (visible by default)

```
project.logger.lifecycle('my message visible by default')
```

Comment: If you just want to log something without configuring anything use `project.logger.lifecycle('my message visible by default')` as @JbirdVegas suggested. You can view the log in the *Gradle console* tab.

Answer (score 83):

Gradle scripts are written in Groovy language. It is possible to log into console your own messages.

If your **Gradle version** of your project is **3.2.1 or above** then there is a simple option for logging in your build file which is to write messages to standard output. Gradle redirects anything written to standard output to it's logging system.

**Example**

```
println 'A message which is logged at QUIET level'
```

Gradle logging system allows us to log message into multiple log levels (LIFECYCLE, QUIET, INFO, DEBUG )

Please go through below link for detailed study

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html

Comment: `println` will not log though the logging frameworks it is a method forward to `System.out.println(String)` method.  This will always print not just at a specific log level.

Comment: Reference on `println` method in groovy: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#println()

Comment: It is taken from release note of Gradle version 3.2.1. I will update my answer

Comment: @JBird: "Gradle redirects anything written to standard output to its logging system at the QUIET log level." (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html, which is for Gradle 4.2.1). So according to this documentation, `println` *will* log through the logging framework. However, I have not been able to successfully test this in practice.

Comment: This works on Android Studio while the accepted solution did not

Comment: @Chisko There currently is no accepted answer. Which one did you mean and why didn't it work? Why didn't you comment there?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan I guess I meant the most voted answer, this was more than 5 years ago

Answer (score 29):

Basically you can print out a message by this gradle script -

```
 println "This is a simple gradle message"
```

but if you want to print a variable in the message then you can do it by the following code

```
def variable = "This is a simple variable"

println "Message: ${variable}"
```

Answer (score 18):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**).

When you use `println` (standard output), it is redirected to log level `QUIET`. So, it is *always* printed in all log levels (when no log level is specified, Gradle defaults to `LIFECYCLE`):

```kotlin
println("I am a log message.")
```

You can also use `logger` property of the `project` implicitly provided in the script:

```kotlin
logger.info("I am an {} log message", "info")
// OR
project.logger.info("I am an {} log message", "info")
```

Here are log levels available in Gradle and how to enable them from command line:

| Order | Name | Command line option | Levels outputted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | `ERROR` | does not have option (always printed) | `ERROR` |
| 5 | `QUIET` | `-q` or `--quiet` | `QUIET` and higher |
| 4 | `WARNING` | `-w` or `--warn` | `WARNING` and higher |
| 3 | `LIFECYCLE` | when no option is provided | `LIFECYCLE` and higher |
| 2 | `INFO` | `-i` or `--info` | `INFO` and higher |
| 1 | `DEBUG` | `-d` or `--debug` | `DEBUG` and higher |

You can also set the log level in *[gradle.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30333837/8583692)* file:

```
org.gradle.logging.level=quiet|warn|lifecycle|info|debug
```

See [Gradle official documentations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) to learn more about logging.

Answer (score 9):

This works in Android Studio for me:

```
println("Log: current build type is $buildTypeName")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own tasks and print values to console.

```
tasks.create("nameOfTest"){
    println("Print anything")
}
```

and from terminal you can run above task

```
./gradlew nameOfTest
```