# Dev mode dependency for gradle in IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

I want to add dependency on `spring-boot-devtools` but only for development.
I try to achieve this by having this snippet in my `build.gradle`:

```
if (project.hasProperty('use-spring-boot-devtools')) {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
}
```

Then I can define in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
use-spring-boot-devtools = true
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work when I run import project in IDEA. I would like to use [answer to related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333837/where-to-put-the-gradle-properties-file#30333929) but still can't figure out how to define environment variable that will affect gradle inside IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use hyphens to concat your key in the `gradle.properties`. Instead define it in camel case:

```
useSpringBootDevtools=true
```

And for your `build.gradle` file, use the following syntax for your conditional dependency:

```
if(useSpringBootDevtools.toBoolean())
{
    // your conditional dependency here
}
```

Make sure to append `toBoolean()` to your key since it's not casted automatically by Gradle.

Comment: this really helped me a lot. I have a requirement to use a common project as dependency. in dev/my machine I simple added common project to build path and add conditional dependency like above only for prod.