# Gradle build parameters in development environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have Spring Boot project with Gradle and I had to put some parameters in the gradle file so I can build to project with different environments.

So for example I use

```
gradlew build docker -Penv_name=prod
```

And I get a custom docker name

```
docker {
  dependsOn build
  name "gcr.io/app-${env_name}/app"
}
```

It's all good but the problem is that I get errors from intelliJ

```
Could not get unknown property 'env_name' for root project
```

Adding `def env_name = ""` obviously solves the problem.

Is there a way to define `env_name` only if it's not already defined, or maybe set default value to it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define some default values in a [`gradle.properties`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) file in the root directory of your Spring Boot project ([see sample from a demo project of mine](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/server/gradle.properties)).

In there you can define all gradle properties, something like

```
env_name = dev
```

When you run the gradle command from the command line with this parameter set, it is overridden and when the command is ran from IntelliJ IDEA the default parameter is used.

**Further readings**

- [Where to put the gradle.properties file in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333837/where-to-put-the-gradle-properties-file)