# Common version management for Gradle and maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, property-files

We have a spring-boot java project which has both maven and Gradle. The problem is with dependencies, each has its own version of dependencies. For example, in maven MySQL dependency is

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
```

Whereas in Gradle, having below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(':demo'))
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.31'
}
```

Is there a way to maintain versions for both maven and Gradle in some commonplace? Like from an external property file inside the project?
Manually syncing versions for both Maven and Gradle is getting cumbersome.

Comment: "which has both" is already bad/probably wrong... Better: have only one(!) (and automatically export/deploy/publish the other.. i think Gradle>maven is "more mature" ...see e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot ..it "maintains" only a gradle build, but exports also to maven

Comment: *export to maven: easily `$ ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`

Comment: You *cannot have* maven-lovers & gradle-fans united in one (build) project! Where should that lead? Atm. gradle2maven seems superior, since it is a 1-liner ...whereas maven2gradle needs like studies & years of XP:)

Comment: @xerx593 : Thanks for the information. I will explore exporting to maven from gradle build.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the `gradle.properties` file for both Gradle and Maven.

For instance, you can have these properties:

```
MYSQL_CONNECTOR_VERSION=8.0.31
ANOTHER_PROPERTY=something
```

**Gradle** looks for `gradle.properties` files in these places ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334916/9213148)):

- The root project directory - maybe the best option for you
- The sub-project directory
- Under gradle user home directory defined by the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable, which if not set defaults to `USER_HOME/.gradle`

Then, in `build.gradle`, you can read these properties like so:

```
task printProps {
    doFirst {
        println MYSQL_CONNECTOR_VERSION
        println ANOTHER_PROPERTY
    }
}
```

As for **Maven**, you can access this file using the *[Properties Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/)*:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>path/to/gradle.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And use them just like you would with the usual Maven properties.

---

### **UPDATE**

It looks like the documentation for the *Properties Maven Plugin* is misleading, or not accurate enough. For the time being, **it's not possible** to read version properties from an external properties file, even though [it's stated](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html):

> The read-project-properties goal reads property files and URLs and
> stores the properties as project properties. It serves as an alternate
> to specifying properties in pom.xml

For more information regarding this issue, follow this GitHub discussion:
https://github.com/mojohaus/properties-maven-plugin/issues/26

Comment: Unfortunately "properties-maven-plugin" won't work for versions. https://github.com/mojohaus/properties-maven-plugin/issues/26.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @shashantrika. I've updated my answer with this information.