# gradlew Failing Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, gradle, jvm, androidx

When I attempt to run some gradle tasks from the command line using the gradlew such as `./gradlew assembleRelease`, I get the following failure. When I run the same task from Android Studio it runs fine.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.3 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.3' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.3 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.3 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.3 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
```

I am trying to compile with JDK 17. I have made sure I'm using the correct version in `jvmToolchain` references as well as where `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` is specified.

I have checked to make sure I'm using the same JDK in my `$JAVA_HOME` variable as is set to be used by Android Studio. I can also confirm this typing the command `./gradlew --version`.

I have invalidated my gradle caches, cleaned the project and also restarted my machine.

In my `gradle-wrapper.properties` I am specifying `gradle-8.3`.

[I've checked](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/09667b963bc653e2a278abfac5b68417214497d8/buildSrc/build.gradle) and the library seems to be built with the `jvmTarget` of 17.

Comment: Do you have `org.gradle.java.home` set in `gradle.properties` [in any of its locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30333929/3169238)?

Comment: Hi! did you manage to solve this issue? 
I had the same problem for several days and even though I thought I was using the right version of Java, I wasn't. My JAVA_HOME wasn't set and every time I ran ./gradlew --version, JVM was 11. is for you set to 17 if you run this command?

First I changed gradle-wrapper.properties and I added this line
org.gradle.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents
then I ran again ./gradlew --version had finally jvm 17

Comment: @SergeiKozelko your comment prompted me to look in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and that's where I found the issue. Please answer this question and I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure gradle's using Java 17.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212790/692167

I personally encountered this in my Bitrise workflow and fixed with a "Set java version" step prior to my "Install missing Android SDK components" step.