# How to install the gradle-3.0 manually

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to set up the new gradel-3.0 but I am getting error like this

```
Error:Cause:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I tried all the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254526/manually-install-gradle-and-use-it-in-android-studio) ,I restarted my laptop also but then also I am getting the same error .How to fix this any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade your gradle build tools to:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'`

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta3` will work too.

Comment: This is out of beta now