# Android studio Discrepancy in gradle versions mentioned in file>project structure and in Terminal gradle -v

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

While trying to evaluate code using sonarqube through terminal, I'm getting this error

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/linuxandroid/.gradle/daemon/2.10/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip

But the gradle version in project structure and /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties is 3.3 which is not the same when checked in terminal. It is showing different gradle versions at the same time.

[gradle -v  from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ntBR.png)

[image: File>Project Structure>Project]

The dependencies in build.gradle(Project:app name) is like this
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

How can solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077386/gradle-error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-3-3-current-version-is-3-2

Comment: @Gugas I had gone through this question before. But the scenario is different. The version is already 3 3 everywhere except when i check in terminal.

Comment: I think you might have two instances of Gradle on your machine, try to set it using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254526/manually-install-gradle-and-use-it-in-android-studio