# Build failed, Cause: error reading zip file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

My android studio was running perfecly yesterday, but today when I started my android studio and want to run an app on mobile the following error occurred,

[image]

I searched on the internet and stackoverflow but no solution is useful

I even manually downloaded the `gradle-4.6-all.zip` from the gradle/distribution and pasted in `~\.gradle\wrapper\dists`, but the error still there.

kindly help me with this.

Comment: Do `clean & build` once

Comment: getting the same error while cleaning the project

Comment: Check more details by adding `--stacktrace` in `command-line options`

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you don't have **unzipped gradle files** in `~\.gradle\wrapper\dists` directory.

Extract the zipped gradle-4.6-all.zip and extract it in 
`~\.gradle\wrapper\dists` directory.

Alternatively ,Android Studio will automatically use the Gradle wrapper and pull the correct version of Gradle. Beneath your Android Studio's project tree, open the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Check for this entry to be:

**`distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`**

Clean rebuild the project.

Download Link for Gradle Versions: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/

References:[Manually install Gradle and use it in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254526/manually-install-gradle-and-use-it-in-android-studio)

Comment: I already did this, I manually downloaded the same version of gradle mentioned in wrapper.properties, I also extacted the files in the dists directory, but the error still there.